# Windows cannot read my 8GB MemoryStick M2 card

Tags: windows-xp, fat32, memorystick, memory-card

I tried inserting a M2 card I was using in my old phone into the memory stick reader on my Windows XP PC (using a M2 to MemoryStick adapter). But the drive comes up as unformatted, and the formatter only offers to format it as 4GB FAT32.

It worked fine when I put it into my PSP and I was able to access the files that way, but the issue still annoys me so I'd appreciate to know why this is.

Is there an issue with using over 4GB MemoryStick on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can depend on how old the Memory stick reader is on your pc.

I have one of the first Sony laptops that included a Memory stick reader and if I put in anything bigger than 4GB's (or it could be 2GB's... I haven't used it in about 10+ years!) I get the same as you. It simply asks to format and you do not get the full size.

Answer (score 0):

Rechecked after your comment.

Are you using Windows XP lower than SP3 patch?
Can you try on a Windows Vista for formatting the M2?

---

Older answer for reference: This could be related to your PSP,
Check this [PSPMod forum thread](http://www.pspmod.com/forums/hardware/38511-m2-8gb-memory-stick.html) on using 8GB M2 memory.

Comment: If you had read my post you would have noticed I said the card WORKED in the PSP, but NOT in my PC.

Comment: It's a fully patched Windows XP. I don't have access to a Vista box with a MemoryStick reader.